# Не компилируется и не запускается программа в RAD STUDIO 10.3

Tags: delphi, компиляция, radstudio

После закрытия окна мисскликнул и сохранил только файл с кодом Паскаля. Теперь при открытии этого файла - работать с визуальными компонентами и кодом можно, но нельзя скомпилировать программу. Прикладываю скриншот кнопки запуска компиляции:[image: серая кнопка, до этого была зелёной]
Можно ли как-то создать проект с паскалевским файлом?

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отличный скриншот! Сразу становится ясно, в чем проблема.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте новый проект и добавьте туда Вашу форму.